# "Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter()" error

Tags: android

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

    private SlideshowViewModel listacompraViewModel;
    ArrayList<String> shoppingList = null;
    ArrayAdapter adapter = null;
    ListView lv =null;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listacompraViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_listacompra);
        listacompraViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;



        shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(shoppingList, "Ovos", "Iogurte", "Bananas");
        shoppingList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Guardanapos", "Comida para cão", "Batom"));
        shoppingList.add("Protetor solar");
        shoppingList.add("Pasta de dentes");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I am trying to setup a shopping list with an Array adapter, but I'm getting the error in the title.
I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the problem, because I don't know to fix this.
Please ignore the items inside the arrays, as they are not in english.

Comment: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);`

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of  `this` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listacompraViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);

       final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_listacompra);
        listacompraViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(shoppingList, "Ovos", "Iogurte", "Bananas");
        shoppingList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Guardanapos", "Comida para cão", "Batom"));
        shoppingList.add("Protetor solar");
        shoppingList.add("Pasta de dentes");
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);
         lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

       return root;


}
```

Comment: That solution makes "shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();" an unreachable statement.